# jQuery .each it counts every link that i copy and paste from textarea

Tags: jquery, split, each

I have this form, that when i open my notepad there is the lists of my links,
I copy it from notepad then paste all the links in the textarea then it should count.

But what im trying to solve is that, when i do copy and paste it will automatically count not when i enter.

My codes are below to explain what my works.

jQuery Code

```
jQuery.fn.wordCount = function(params) {
    var p =  { counterElement:"display_count" };
    var total_words;

    if(params) {
        jQuery.extend(p, params);
    }

    //for each keypress function on text areas
    this.keypress(function() {
        total_words=this.value.split("\n").length;
        jQuery('#'+p.counterElement).html(total_words);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){                           
    $('#txtLinks').wordCount();
});
```

my Form

```
<form method="post">
<textarea name="texturl" rows="10" cols="20" id="txtLinks" class="textarea-addlinks"></textarea>
</form>
```

and the links are

```
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Are_aware_of_the_Uncomplicated_strategies_to_post_sms_to_help_all_people
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Below_To_acquire_pizza_hut_vouchers
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Brand-new_business_model_innovation_specialists
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Ery_at_times_a_good_Pizza_Express_Voucher_Are_usually_for_exciting
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Gain_knowledge_of_on_the_subject_of_signs_of_depression
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Get_yourself_a_dvd_swimming_pool_covers_currently
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Simple_and_standard_symptoms_of_the_flu
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=Speaking_about_the_necessities_regarding_tinnitus_miracle:
http://09-flex-actionscript-it.gnstudio.com/index.php?title=The_best_places_to_secure_cheap_supplements_web_based
```

The count value should be 9.
Is there any way that there is no need to press enter i mean it will automatically count the links? By the way --how it counts? it count bye new link.

thanks guys

Comment: Why not change the `.keyPress()` event to the `.change()`?

Comment: `this.on('keypress paste', function() {...}`

Comment: change() was working thank you guys.

Comment: I'd do this : http://jsfiddle.net/js7Qn/1/ to make it work with pasted content added by just clicking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/js7Qn/

I used:

```
$('#txtLinks').keyup(...
```